# Sort Array and use the result for an if statement

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

The program first asks the user to input two pet names. It will then print their anger level as follows:

```
Oh cool, Poodle is a very unique name!
Poodle is feeling tetchy!
Oh cool, Ollie is a very unique name!
Ollie is DANGEROUS RIGHT NOW!!!.
```

It will then ask you whether you would like to take care of the angrier pet first. I've done this in the method called sort(...) and this is where i'm stuck.

I would like it to execute the feeding/singing part of the code, which occurs in petInteraction(...) on the angrier pet first, if the user typed in Yes when asked to do so, if no then run the code as usual.

Here's the full code im working with:

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
public class alientpetprogram
{

public static void main(String[] args)
{   
    //Generates a random value from 1-10 for the pet's emotional state
    int[] EmotionalState = new int [3];
    Random emotion = new Random();
    for(int i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
    {
    int hungerLVL = emotion.nextInt(10) + 1;
    EmotionalState[0] = hungerLVL;

    int thirstLVL = emotion.nextInt(10) + 1;
    EmotionalState[1] = thirstLVL;

    int irritabilityLVL = emotion.nextInt(10) + 1;
    EmotionalState[2] = irritabilityLVL;
    }

    String [] petName = new String [2];

    petEmotion(EmotionalState, petName);      
    System.exit(0);
} //ENDS main

    public static String[] petInteraction(int[] EmotionalState, String [] petName) //Use this further on in petEmotion()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) //A for loop is used to store two pet's in an array. An emotional state is then assigned to the pet.
        {
            petName[i] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is your pet called?");
            System.out.println("Oh cool, " + petName[i] + " is a very unique name!");

            if (EmotionalState[0] == 1 || EmotionalState[0] == 2 || EmotionalState[0] == 3)
            {
                System.out.println(petName[i] + " is feeling Calm.");
            }
            else if (EmotionalState[0] == 4 || EmotionalState[0] == 5 || EmotionalState[0] == 6 )
            {
                System.out.println(petName[i] + " is feeling tetchy!");
            }
            else if (EmotionalState[0] == 7 || EmotionalState[0] == 8 || EmotionalState[0] == 9 || EmotionalState[0] == 10 )
            {
                System.out.println(petName[i] + " is DANGEROUS RIGHT NOW!!!.");
            }
                EmotionalState[0] = (int)(Math.random()*0+9);

        }   
        sort(EmotionalState, petName);
        return petName;
    } //ENDS petInteraction

    public static void sort(int[] EmotionalState, String [] petName)
    {
        Arrays.sort(EmotionalState);
        for (int SortAnger = 0; SortAnger < EmotionalState.length; SortAnger++)
        {
            String carePet = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Would you like to take care of the angrier pet first?");
            if(carePet.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes"))
            {

            }
            else if(carePet.equalsIgnoreCase("No"))
            {

            }
            System.out.println(""+ EmotionalState[SortAnger]);
        }


    }   

                public static void petEmotion(int[] EmotionalState, String [] petName) 
                {  
                      String[] petsName = petInteraction(EmotionalState, petName);

                      String userinput;
                      userinput=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("choose how many rounds?"); //Allows the user to set the rounds
                      int roundsuggestion=Integer.parseInt(userinput);

                        for (int round =1; round <=roundsuggestion; round++) //sets the amount of rounds the game runs for.           
                        {
                        System.out.println("Round " + roundsuggestion);                   
                        System.out.println(petsName[0] + "'s irrtability level is " + EmotionalState[2]);
                        System.out.println(petsName[0] + "'s thirst level is " + EmotionalState[1]);
                        System.out.println(petsName[0] + "'s hunger level is " + EmotionalState[0]); 

                        EmotionalState[0] = (int)(Math.random()*0+9);
                        EmotionalState[1] = (int)(Math.random()*0+9);
                        EmotionalState[2] = (int)(Math.random()*0+9);

                        System.out.println(petsName[1] + "'s irrtability level is " + EmotionalState[2]);
                        System.out.println(petsName[1] + "'s thirst level is " + EmotionalState[1]);
                        System.out.println(petsName[1] + "'s hunger level is " + EmotionalState[0]);   

                  //The for loop below is used to reduce the Thirst, Hunger and Irritability levels for pet one and two
                       for(int y=1; y<=2; y++)
                       {

                            String askToReduceIrritable = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Would you like to sing for " + petsName[0]  + " in order to lower the pets irritability level?");

                            if (askToReduceIrritable.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes"))
                            {
                                EmotionalState[2] = EmotionalState[2] - 1;
                                System.out.println(petsName[0] + "'s irrtability level is now " + EmotionalState[2]);                           
                            }   

                            String askToReduceThirst = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Would you like to give " + petsName[0] + " some water in order to reduce the thirst level?");

                            if (askToReduceThirst.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes"))
                            {
                                EmotionalState[1] = EmotionalState[1] - 1;
                                System.out.println(petsName[0] + "'s thirst level is now " + EmotionalState[1]);                           
                            }   

                            String askToReduceHunger = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Would you like to give " + petsName[0] + " some food in order to reduce the hunger level?");

                            if (askToReduceHunger.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes"))
                            {
                                EmotionalState[0] = EmotionalState[0] - 1;
                                System.out.println(petsName[0] + "'s hunger level is now " + EmotionalState[0]);                           
                            }           
                            System.out.println("");
                            System.out.println("You will now take care of the second pet");

                            String askToReduceIrritableTwo = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Would you like to sing for " + petsName[1]  + " in order to lower the pets irritability level?");

                            if (askToReduceIrritableTwo.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes"))
                            {
                                EmotionalState[2] = EmotionalState[2] - 1;
                                System.out.println(petsName[1] + "'s irrtability level is now " + EmotionalState[2]);                           
                            }   

                            String askToReduceThirstTwo = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Would you like to give " + petsName[1] + " some water in order to reduce the thirst level?");

                            if (askToReduceThirstTwo.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes"))
                            {
                                EmotionalState[1] = EmotionalState[1] - 1;
                                System.out.println(petsName[1] + "'s thirst level is now " + EmotionalState[1]);                           
                            }   

                            String askToReduceHungerTwo = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Would you like to give " + petsName[1] + " some food in order to reduce the hunger level?");

                            if (askToReduceHungerTwo.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes"))
                            {
                                EmotionalState[0] = EmotionalState[0] - 1;
                                System.out.println(petsName[1] + "'s hunger level is now " + EmotionalState[0]);                           
                            }           
                            String exitGame = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Would you like to exit the game? Type yes/no");

                            if (exitGame.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes"))
                            {
                                System.exit(0);                       
                            }
                            else
                            System.out.println("");
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "A new round has begun!");

                        } // END second loop
           } // END first loop
                }//ENDS petEmotion                 

} //ENDS Class alientpetprogram
```

Comment: Did my answer helped you? If you have any question, feel free to ask!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to correlate the state with the pet name.I'll advise you to create a class `Pet` with a name and its emotional state which implements the `Comparable` interface so you could easily sort an array of Pets according to their anger state.

```
public class Pet implements Comparable<Pet> {
   private String name;
   private int state;

   // Add required basic methods here

   int compareTo(Pet pet) {
      return state - pet.getState();
   }
}
```

Then define your array as :

```
Pet pets[] = // Initialize with Pet objects
```

Then sort the array as you already did :

```
Arrays.sort(pets);
```

And now the first object in the array will be the angriest pet and you can easily extract his name with the proper class getter method.

Comment: Isn't it possible to achieve what I needed by using the `String carePet = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Would you like to take care of the angrier pet first?");
            if(carePet.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes"))
            {

            }
            else if(carePet.equalsIgnoreCase("No"))
            {

            }
            System.out.println(""+ EmotionalState[SortAnger]);`

format that I currently have, because i don't know how I would implement your suggestion in my code.

Comment: Right now its not possible since the feeling parts are printed as soon as the pets got created, you are sorting afterwards. So first of all the user needs to create the pets and then you can ask if he wants the angriest one to print the feeling statements. Giorashc design hint is making your life easier, I would also recommend that since right now your pets and the emotions are loosely coupled. Do you know what I mean? :)

Answer (score 0):

Okay I changed some stuff, from here on I hope you know which direction it should take. :)
There are still errors in there now, you have to fix them. Why are u working with 3 emotional states if you have two pets? You shouldnt use the emotionalState (first letter lowercase for java convention) array anymore after you created the pets and gave them their emotion state.

Just some additional information: Java is an `Object-Oriented Programming` language, because you can represent real objects as classes (and therefore create instances=object via `new`). Thats why the additional class `Pet` should be used, since you represent a real-world thing with it. :) (ofc not only things that actually exist in our world, aliens are also allowed :P)

Below is the code I changed so far, as mentioned in the beginning you must revise the whole code since some stuff is not compatible anymore.

Hope this helps!

Class `Pet`:

```
public class Pet implements Comparable<Pet> {
private String name;
private int state;

/**
* @return Returns the state.
*/
public int getState()
{
  return state;
}

/**
* @param state The state to set.
*/
public void setState(int state)
{
   this.state = state;
}

public int compareTo(Pet pet) {
   return state - pet.getState();
}

/**
 * @return Returns the name.
 */
public String getName()
{
   return name;
}

/**
 * @param name The name to set.
 */
public void setName(String name)
{
   this.name = name;
}
 }
```

Class `alientpetprogram`:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class alientpetprogram
{


 public static void main(String[] args)
{   
   //Generates a random value from 1-10 for the pet's emotional state
   int[] emotionalState = new int [3];
   Random emotion = new Random();
   for(int i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
   {
   int hungerLVL = emotion.nextInt(10) + 1;
   emotionalState[0] = hungerLVL;

   int thirstLVL = emotion.nextInt(10) + 1;
   emotionalState[1] = thirstLVL;

   int irritabilityLVL = emotion.nextInt(10) + 1;
   emotionalState[2] = irritabilityLVL;
   }

   //fill the array already with 2 pets
   Pet pets[] = new Pet[]{new Pet(), new Pet()};

   petEmotion(emotionalState, pets);      
   System.exit(0);
} //ENDS main

   public static Pet[] petInteraction(int[] emotionalState, Pet[] pets) //Use this further on in petEmotion()
   {

       for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) //A for loop is used to store two pet's in an array. An emotional state is then assigned to the pet.
       {
           String tempPetName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is your pet called?");
           pets[i].setName(tempPetName);
           pets[i].setState(emotionalState[i]);
           System.out.println("Oh cool, " + pets[i].getName() + " is a very unique name!");
       }   

       Arrays.sort(pets);

       String carePet = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Would you like to take care of the angrier pet first?");
       if(carePet.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes"))
       {
          for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) //A for loop is used to store two pet's in an array. An emotional state is then assigned to the pet.
          {
              if (emotionalState[0] == 1 || emotionalState[0] == 2 || emotionalState[0] == 3)
              {
                  System.out.println(pets[i] + " is feeling Calm.");
              }
              else if (emotionalState[0] == 4 || emotionalState[0] == 5 || emotionalState[0] == 6 )
              {
                  System.out.println(pets[i] + " is feeling tetchy!");
              }
              else if (emotionalState[0] == 7 || emotionalState[0] == 8 || emotionalState[0] == 9 || emotionalState[0] == 10 )
              {
                  System.out.println(pets[i] + " is DANGEROUS RIGHT NOW!!!.");
              }
                  emotionalState[0] = (int)(Math.random()*0+9);
          }  
       }
       else if(carePet.equalsIgnoreCase("No"))
       {
          for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) //A for loop is used to store two pet's in an array. An emotional state is then assigned to the pet.
          {
              if (emotionalState[0] == 1 || emotionalState[0] == 2 || emotionalState[0] == 3)
              {
                  System.out.println(pets[i] + " is feeling Calm.");
              }
              else if (emotionalState[0] == 4 || emotionalState[0] == 5 || emotionalState[0] == 6 )
              {
                  System.out.println(pets[i] + " is feeling tetchy!");
              }
              else if (emotionalState[0] == 7 || emotionalState[0] == 8 || emotionalState[0] == 9 || emotionalState[0] == 10 )
              {
                  System.out.println(pets[i] + " is DANGEROUS RIGHT NOW!!!.");
              }
                  emotionalState[0] = (int)(Math.random()*0+9);
          }  
       }

       return pets;
   } //ENDS petInteraction


               public static void petEmotion(int[] emotionalState, Pet[] pets) 
               {  
                     pets = petInteraction(emotionalState, pets);

                     String userinput;
                     userinput=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("choose how many rounds?"); //Allows the user to set the rounds
                     int roundsuggestion=Integer.parseInt(userinput);

                       for (int round =1; round <=roundsuggestion; round++) //sets the amount of rounds the game runs for.           
                       {
                       System.out.println("Round " + roundsuggestion);                   
                       System.out.println(pets[0].getName() + "'s irrtability level is " + emotionalState[2]);
                       System.out.println(pets[0].getName() + "'s thirst level is " + emotionalState[1]);
                       System.out.println(pets[0].getName() + "'s hunger level is " + emotionalState[0]); 

                       emotionalState[0] = (int)(Math.random()*0+9);
                       emotionalState[1] = (int)(Math.random()*0+9);
                       emotionalState[2] = (int)(Math.random()*0+9);

                       System.out.println(pets[1].getName() + "'s irrtability level is " + emotionalState[2]);
                       System.out.println(pets[1].getName() + "'s thirst level is " + emotionalState[1]);
                       System.out.println(pets[1].getName() + "'s hunger level is " + emotionalState[0]);   

                 //The for loop below is used to reduce the Thirst, Hunger and Irritability levels for pet one and two
                      for(int y=1; y<=2; y++)
                      {

                           String askToReduceIrritable = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Would you like to sing for " + pets[1].getName()  + " in order to lower the pets irritability level?");

                           if (askToReduceIrritable.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes"))
                           {
                              emotionalState[2] = emotionalState[2] - 1;
                               System.out.println(pets[0].getName() + "'s irrtability level is now " + emotionalState[2]);                           
                           }   

                           String askToReduceThirst = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Would you like to give " + pets[1].getName() + " some water in order to reduce the thirst level?");

                           if (askToReduceThirst.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes"))
                           {
                              emotionalState[1] = emotionalState[1] - 1;
                               System.out.println(pets[0].getName() + "'s thirst level is now " + emotionalState[1]);                           
                           }   

                           String askToReduceHunger = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Would you like to give " + pets[1].getName() + " some food in order to reduce the hunger level?");

                           if (askToReduceHunger.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes"))
                           {
                              emotionalState[0] = emotionalState[0] - 1;
                               System.out.println(pets[0].getName() + "'s hunger level is now " + emotionalState[0]);                           
                           }           
                           System.out.println("");
                           System.out.println("You will now take care of the second pet");

                           String askToReduceIrritableTwo = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Would you like to sing for " + pets[1].getName()  + " in order to lower the pets irritability level?");

                           if (askToReduceIrritableTwo.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes"))
                           {
                              emotionalState[2] = emotionalState[2] - 1;
                               System.out.println(pets[1].getName() + "'s irrtability level is now " + emotionalState[2]);                           
                           }   

                           String askToReduceThirstTwo = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Would you like to give " + pets[1].getName() + " some water in order to reduce the thirst level?");

                           if (askToReduceThirstTwo.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes"))
                           {
                              emotionalState[1] = emotionalState[1] - 1;
                               System.out.println(pets[1].getName() + "'s thirst level is now " + emotionalState[1]);                           
                           }   

                           String askToReduceHungerTwo = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Would you like to give " + pets[1].getName() + " some food in order to reduce the hunger level?");

                           if (askToReduceHungerTwo.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes"))
                           {
                              emotionalState[0] = emotionalState[0] - 1;
                               System.out.println(pets[1].getName() + "'s hunger level is now " + emotionalState[0]);                           
                           }           
                           String exitGame = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Would you like to exit the game? Type yes/no");

                           if (exitGame.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes"))
                           {
                               System.exit(0);                       
                           }
                           else
                           System.out.println("");
                           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "A new round has begun!");

                       } // END second loop
          } // END first loop
               }//ENDS petEmotion                 

} //ENDS Class alientpetprogram
```